# Weird behavior from Octave's atan2

Tags: matlab, octave, atan2

I'm trying to port some Octave code to Java. I'm trying out atan2 so I have the following tries

```
octave3.2:53> m1 = [1,2;3,4]
m1 =

   1   2
   3   4

octave3.2:54> m2=[5,6;7,8]
m2 =

   5   6
   7   8

octave3.2:55> atan2(m1,m2)
ans =

   0.19740   0.32175
   0.40489   0.46365

octave3.2:56> atan(1/5)
ans =  0.19740
octave3.2:57> atan(2/6)
ans =  0.32175
octave3.2:58> atan(3/7)
ans =  0.40489
octave3.2:59> atan(4/8)
ans =  0.46365
```

So it seems to me that atan2 applies atan cell-wise, to the quotient of the first argument divided by the second argument. I got this well in Java. However, the following piece of code gives off something weird...

```
y
x
theta = atan2(y,x)
```

For which I get a trace something like,

```
y =

  -0.50000  -0.50000  -0.50000  -0.50000  -0.50000  -0.50000  -0.50000  -0.50000  -0.50000  -0.50000
  -0.40000  -0.40000  -0.40000  -0.40000  -0.40000  -0.40000  -0.40000  -0.40000  -0.40000  -0.40000
  -0.30000  -0.30000  -0.30000  -0.30000  -0.30000  -0.30000  -0.30000  -0.30000  -0.30000  -0.30000
  -0.20000  -0.20000  -0.20000  -0.20000  -0.20000  -0.20000  -0.20000  -0.20000  -0.20000  -0.20000
  -0.10000  -0.10000  -0.10000  -0.10000  -0.10000  -0.10000  -0.10000  -0.10000  -0.10000  -0.10000
   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000
   0.20000   0.20000   0.20000   0.20000   0.20000   0.20000   0.20000   0.20000   0.20000   0.20000
   0.30000   0.30000   0.30000   0.30000   0.30000   0.30000   0.30000   0.30000   0.30000   0.30000
   0.40000   0.40000   0.40000   0.40000   0.40000   0.40000   0.40000   0.40000   0.40000   0.40000

x =

  -0.50000  -0.40000  -0.30000  -0.20000  -0.10000   0.00000   0.10000   0.20000   0.30000   0.40000
  -0.50000  -0.40000  -0.30000  -0.20000  -0.10000   0.00000   0.10000   0.20000   0.30000   0.40000
  -0.50000  -0.40000  -0.30000  -0.20000  -0.10000   0.00000   0.10000   0.20000   0.30000   0.40000
  -0.50000  -0.40000  -0.30000  -0.20000  -0.10000   0.00000   0.10000   0.20000   0.30000   0.40000
  -0.50000  -0.40000  -0.30000  -0.20000  -0.10000   0.00000   0.10000   0.20000   0.30000   0.40000
  -0.50000  -0.40000  -0.30000  -0.20000  -0.10000   0.00000   0.10000   0.20000   0.30000   0.40000
  -0.50000  -0.40000  -0.30000  -0.20000  -0.10000   0.00000   0.10000   0.20000   0.30000   0.40000
  -0.50000  -0.40000  -0.30000  -0.20000  -0.10000   0.00000   0.10000   0.20000   0.30000   0.40000
  -0.50000  -0.40000  -0.30000  -0.20000  -0.10000   0.00000   0.10000   0.20000   0.30000   0.40000
  -0.50000  -0.40000  -0.30000  -0.20000  -0.10000   0.00000   0.10000   0.20000   0.30000   0.40000

theta =

  -2.35619  -2.24554  -2.11122  -1.95130  -1.76819  -1.57080  -1.37340  -1.19029  -1.03038  -0.89606
  -2.46685  -2.35619  -2.21430  -2.03444  -1.81577  -1.57080  -1.32582  -1.10715  -0.92730  -0.78540
  -2.60117  -2.49809  -2.35619  -2.15880  -1.89255  -1.57080  -1.24905  -0.98279  -0.78540  -0.64350
  -2.76109  -2.67795  -2.55359  -2.35619  -2.03444  -1.57080  -1.10715  -0.78540  -0.58800  -0.46365
  -2.94420  -2.89661  -2.81984  -2.67795  -2.35619  -1.57080  -0.78540  -0.46365  -0.32175  -0.24498
   3.14159   3.14159   3.14159   3.14159   3.14159   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
   2.94420   2.89661   2.81984   2.67795   2.35619   1.57080   0.78540   0.46365   0.32175   0.24498
   2.76109   2.67795   2.55359   2.35619   2.03444   1.57080   1.10715   0.78540   0.58800   0.46365
   2.60117   2.49809   2.35619   2.15880   1.89255   1.57080   1.24905   0.98279   0.78540   0.64350
   2.46685   2.35619   2.21430   2.03444   1.81577   1.57080   1.32582   1.10715   0.92730   0.78540
```

What's with that? I think the first cell of theta should ~0.785398. The other cells seem wrong too. Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on my own. `atan2` isn't simply `atan` applied cell-wise. The sign of the operands matter as well.

For more info see: http://sunsite.univie.ac.at/textbooks/octave/octave_17.html

And then for how to implement `atan2` by yourself (as I'm doing) see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: Additionally, if you would like to implement it in _Java_, it turns out that Java really has an `atan2` function...no more bothering with conditionals, etc.: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2(double, double)

Answer (score 0):

Atan2 is not quiet atan as it takes into account the quadrant.

see:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

your first case is `atan(x/y) - Pi`